# select all persons from the engagedpersons table attended to by a particular career guider

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I want to construct a query whereby I can be able select all the persons attended to by a particular career guider. A person can be attended to by any number of career guiders. I am thinking of a query this way but cannot get my head around it as am I new to symfony.

`Select all persons where EngagedPersons.Persons id=1 and EngagedPersons.careerguides email = "email".`

Below is the table structure of my attempt

```
|persons |          |engagedpersons|         |careerguide|
|id      |          |id            |         |id          |
|name    |          |uniqucode     |         |name        |
                    |personfk      |         |specialty   |
                    |careerguidefk |
                    |guidesemail   |
```

Please kindly assist!

Comment: It's probably easier if you post the entities (without the methods, just the classes + fields).

Comment: I have mapped out the relationship at the entity and it appears fine at that level but I just need the doctrine query.

Comment: The doctrine query is easier to write if we have the exact mappings, that's why I asked. It's probably along the lines of `SELECT p FROM AppBundle:Persons p LEFT JOIN p.careerguide c WHERE c.email = 'email';`. Your table doesn't have an email associated with careerguide for example, while your "example query" above queries for exactly that. That doesn't make it easy to give you an exact answer.

Comment: where did u use the id of the personfk in the engagedpersons table

Comment: I didn't, that's why I asked for your mapping information. Normally you'd have something like a many-to-many relationship in persons and careerguide entities. Doctrine has that mapping informations and hence knows the keys.

Comment: ok. hold on let me show my mappings

Comment: there is no direct relationship between persons and careerguides entities. the only relationship exist is between engagedpersons entity as the join table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145536/discussion-between-parker-and-cckep).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145536/discussion-between-parker-and-cckep):

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
$repository = $em->getRepository("PalmyraApiBundle:Registration");

$queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder('registration');

$queryBuilder 
    ->join('registration.engagedsuper', 'engagedActivities')
    ->join('engagedActivities.engagedweakgiver', 'caregiver')
    ->where('registration.id = :id')
    ->andWhere('caregiver.email = :email')
    ->setParameter('id', $id)
    ->setParameter('email', $email);
```